# Can not save array into database by rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, curl

I am trying to make a recipe website and I got some problems when I try to do a curl request to save my data as an array into my database. I used rails for my backend, and psql for my database.

**Migration**

```
class CreateRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration 
    def change
       create_table :recipes do |t|
              t.text :instruction, array: true, default: []
       end
    end
end
```

**Model**

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   serialize :instruction,Array
end
```

**Controller**

```
def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
    **_binding.pry_**
    current_user.recipes << @recipe

    if @recipe.save
      render json: @recipe, status: :created, location: @recipe
    else
      render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipes)
        .permit(:name, :category, instruction: [])
end
```

**Curl request**

```
curl --include --request POST http://localhost:3000/recipes \
  --header "Authorization: Token token=........" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
    "recipes": {
      "name": "an example recipe",
      "category": "fry",
      "instruction": ["do it", "ignore it"]
        }
      }'
```

After I test with pry,

```
pry(#<RecipesController>)> @recipe
=> #<Recipe:0x007fa0aeafa770 id: nil, name: "an example recipe", category: "fry", instruction: [], user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

pry(#<RecipesController>)> recipe_params
=> {"name"=>"an example recipe", "category"=>"fry", "instruction"=>["do it", "ignore it"]}
```

So could anyone let me know what's the problem? And how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `serialize :instruction, Array` from your `Recipe` class and it should work.

The reason the `instruction` attribute doesn't get assigned with `serialize` is that the latter takes an object and serializes it to YAML. The model's array-typed attribute, in turn, expects a plain ruby array.

`serialize` facility is for storing arbitrary objects in a text form, usually for subsequent instantiation. It is not necessary to perform serialization for array attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much~ It solved the problem. But I am having trouble with the nested attributes for child table for my recipe. Would you mind take a look at it? Many thanks for helping. I am a newbie for rails~